# Nuget restore command from different directory

Tags: nuget, nuget-package-restore

I try to run the following nuget command , 
in the  "D:\work\Development\" directory there is solution file

> nuget.exe restore  D:\work\Development\

I received an error

> Could not find a part of the path C:\work\Development

When I copy the nuget.exe file to the directory D:\work\Development and run resotre like so

```
nuget.exe restore
```

from there it works

How can I make restore work from another directory than the one my solution is in?

Comment: Please show the full nuget command line you are using and where your solution/project/packages.config is.

Comment: updated my question with more information

Comment: The command line uses the d: drive but the error message refers to the c: drive. Then you talk about copying nuget.exe to the c: drive again. Is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I ended up doing is using restore from with a relative path like so :

```
nuget.exe restore ..\
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass in the path to the .sln file, such as D:\work\Development\mysolution.sln or path to the packages.config file.

Please refer to this doc for how to use the nuget.exe restore command.

http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/command-line-reference#Restore_command

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue getting a relative path to work, but in my case I was accessing the nuget.exe in a subfolder as well as trying to restore packages in another folder.

I realised that the restore command path is based on the directory you are running the command from, not the directory the nuget.exe file is in.

eg.  If your nuget.exe file is in a **Projects\.nuget** subfolder, and you are in the root directory (one up from Projects), running this will restore any packages for a solution that is in the Projects subfolder.

```
  Projects\.nuget\nuget.exe restore Projects
```